# javascript callbacks not working async way

Tags: javascript

As I was trying to understand js callback I came across this problem.
   Here I am trying to alert `aa`  after `2500 ms` ie when value of aa is resolved but I am getting result as 1 .Why?
I think `aa` is undefined here,but b() is in call stack .It should resolve actual value of `aa`.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

```js
function a(b){
    var aa = b();
    
    setTimeout(function(){
    alert(aa)
    },3000)
    }
    
    function b() {
    return setTimeout(function() {
    return 'alert this value !';
    },2500)
    }
    
    a(b);
```

Comment: That `1` is the timer-reference to your second `setTimeout()`. You can not return a value out of a `setTimeout()` callback like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return a value from an async function like that. One way to get a similar behavior would be to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
async function a(b){
    var aa = await b();

    setTimeout(function(){
      alert(aa)
     },3000)

)

function b() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve( 'alert this value !' );
    },2500)

  }
}

a(b);
```

When you don't have `async`/ `await` at your disposal, you can also use the `then()` callback of the promise in `a()`:

```
function a(b){
    b().then( (value) => {
       setTimeout(function(){
         alert(value)
       },3000)
    });
)
```